# What is my mistake in implementing Foreign Key with EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently in the process of learning ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF 6. Right now I am stuck with declaring a foreign key with Fluent API and then seeding data to the declared tables.
Here's the code I have:

**Models:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Anime> DirectedAnimes { get; set; }
}

public class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    public Person Director { get; set; }
}


public class AnimeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Anime> Animes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Anime>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Director)
            .WithMany(p => p.DirectedAnimes)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.DirectorId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Seeding data:**

```
public class AnimeInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AnimeDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(AnimeDbContext context)
    {   
        var persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Id = 1 },
            new Person { Id = 2 }
        };
        var animes = new List<Anime>
        {
            new Anime { DirectorId = 1 },
            new Anime { DirectorId = 2 }
        };
        persons.ForEach(p => context.Persons.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();
        animes.ForEach(a => context.Animes.Add(a));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But when I fetch `Anime` objects they have expected `DirectorId` values, but their `Director` properties are`null`:

```
var director = (new AnimeDbContext()).Animes.First().Director; //null
var directorId = (new AnimeDbContext()).Animes.First().DirectorId; //1
```

Entity framework knows about the foreign key though, because adding `new Anime {DirectorId = 3}` in the `Seed` method results in a runtime error.

I am pretty sure that my mistake is very dumb and is caused by me not following examples precisely, but I've been struggling with this problem for a while already and still can't figure it out. I would very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigation-property is not virtual and thus cannot be overridden by the DynamicProxy.

Change it like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Anime> DirectedAnimes { get; set; }
}

public class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Director { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb mistake caused by not following exaples indeed. Adding virtual helped me.